# Why Tornado can't detect connection closed from IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, tornado, long-polling

I try to implement "Long polling" by Tornado+Jquery. There's problem that: after a polling established, I close the IE(not other browser) the connection still alive and the program keep going until reach my exit condition.

server

```
class Poll(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous    
    def post(self):   
        self.get_data(callback=self.async_callback(self.on_finish))  
        print("Exiting from async.")    

    def get_data(self, callback,t=30):
        data={}
        data["t"]=datetime.datetime.now()
        if self.request.connection.stream.closed():
            print "Connection closed"
            return  
        if t: 
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(time.time() + 2, lambda: self.get_data(callback, t-1)) 
        else: 
            callback(data) 

    def on_finish(self,data):
        self.write(json.dumps(data))
        self.finish()
```

Client:

```
$.ajax({url: "/poll",                 
    type: "POST",                 
    dataType: "json",
    async:true,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data)    
        interval = window.setTimeout(ldy.poll, 0);
    }
});
```

If I use FF or Chrome. When I close the browser, **self.request.connection.stream.closed()** will turn to TRUE the problem returned but for IE it always False. So that if user switch between two pages(using long polling) the resources of the server quickly exhausted and every click will be hang until one polling exit.
Why? and how to sovle it. Help! Help! T_T

Comment: possible duplicate of [The connection does not timeout while downloading file from internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135003/the-connection-does-not-timeout-while-downloading-file-from-internet)