# Set timeout for InternetReadFile (WinInet + Delphi)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, wininet

My application needs to process a list of urls, by retrieving their text content. My internet connection is started by

```
myTimeOut:= 2000;
InternetSetOption(nil, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@myTimeOut), SizeOf(myTimeOut));
InternetSetOption(nil, INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@myTimeOut), SizeOf(myTimeOut));
InternetSetOption(nil, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@myTimeOut), SizeOf(myTimeOut));
```

I'm launching separate threads for each url reading

```
(...)
read_url_threads[thread_counter]:= TReadURLThread.Create(false);
read_url_threads[thread_counter].FreeOnTerminate:= False;
read_url_threads[thread_counter].myURL:= target_url_list[i];
read_url_threads[thread_counter].output_filename:= local_output_filename;
read_url_threads[thread_counter].NetHandle:= NetHandle;
read_url_threads[thread_counter].limit_text_size:= max_length_url;
hArr[thread_counter]:= read_url_threads[thread_counter].Handle;
(...)
if (thread_counter >= max_threads) or
   (thread_counter >= (target_url_list.Count)) then

   repeat
     rWait:= WaitForMultipleObjects(thread_counter, @hArr,True, 100);
     Application.ProcessMessages;
   until rWait <> WAIT_TIMEOUT;
(...)
```

Inside the thread execution I retrieve the url content by:

```
   if Assigned(NetHandle) and (not EndsText('.pdf',url)) then
    try
      UrlHandle := InternetOpenUrl(NetHandle, PChar(url), nil, 0, 0, 0);
      if Assigned(UrlHandle) then
        try
          repeat
            InternetReadFile(UrlHandle, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BytesRead);
            SetString(StrBuffer, PAnsiChar(@Buffer[0]), BytesRead);
            Result := Result + StrBuffer;
          until BytesRead = 0;
        finally
          InternetCloseHandle(UrlHandle);
        end;
```

My problem is setting the timeout for the InternetReadFile routine. With some urls it gets stuck sometimes for whole minutes. What would be the best way to force a timeout in this cycle?

Comment: Try this related question [The connection does not timeout while downloading file from internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135003/the-connection-does-not-timeout-while-downloading-file-from-internet)

Comment: been there already... I was hoping there was a new suggestion. If not, how can a "forced thread timeout" can be implemented (never done this...). I've already implemented the thread class.

Comment: I think you might be able to use InternetCloseHandle (from a separate monitoring thread). Consider Indy's TIdHTTP, which has a read timeout property. Indy's also cross-platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the configured timeout has no effect (which is a known bug), then you should close the connection handle, which will force the associated function to fail, thereby returning control to your program. Microsoft article [Q224318](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q224318), "How to control connection timeout value by creating second thread," describes how to do that. (You need a separate thread because the other thread is stuck waiting for `InternetReadFile` to return.)

Comment: would you go with keeping a timer in the main thread, iterating over the above declared read_url_threads array and checking a "to-be-added" start_time variable in the secondary threads?

Comment: working link to MS article: https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/224318