# Connect Timeout in InternetSetOption does not work

Tags: delphi

In theory connection attempt should terminate after 5 seconds. However in practice I still get infinite timeout. Is there any way to terminate connection from outside. For example I could use timer and then execute proper function to abort. Another nasty workaround would be fire thread and kill it with TerminateThread function.

```
function DownloadFile(URL, {User, Pass,} FileName: string): Boolean;
const
  BufferSize = 1024;
var
 hSession, hURL: HInternet;
 Buffer: array[1..BufferSize] of Byte;
 BufferLen,Connect_timeout: DWORD;
 F: File;
 User,Pass:string;
begin
  User:='';
  Pass:='';

  Result := False;
  hSession := InternetOpen('', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0) ;

  Connect_timeout := 5000 ;
  InternetSetOption(hSession, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@Connect_timeout), sizeof(Connect_timeout));

  // Establish the secure connection
  InternetConnect (
 hSession,
 PChar(URL),
 INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT,
 PChar(User),
 PChar(Pass),
 INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,
 0,
 0
 );

try
    hURL := InternetOpenURL(hSession, PChar(URL), nil, 0, 0, 0) ;
try
  AssignFile(f, FileName);
  Rewrite(f,1);
  try
    repeat
      InternetReadFile(hURL, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BufferLen) ;
      BlockWrite(f, Buffer, BufferLen)
    until BufferLen = 0;
  finally
    CloseFile(f) ;
    Result := True;
  end;
finally
  InternetCloseHandle(hURL)
end
finally
  InternetCloseHandle(hSession)
end;
end;
```

Comment: You didn't mention at which point the action takes a long time to timeout, but I guess at `InternetReadFile` because you missed to set `INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT` option. But follow e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11583798/960757) to see that MS had some issues even with that timeout (cannot find the linked KB article in English, so here is [in Japanese](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/kb/224318)).

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your answer. I've noticed another odd behaviour with timeout value. Regardless what I enter timeout always takes 12 seconds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The connection does not timeout while downloading file from internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135003/the-connection-does-not-timeout-while-downloading-file-from-internet)

Comment: Yes it does not work. Implement it using threads or use Indy.